# Spring unable to get form values

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Im using the below servlet to get the form values, when the form is posted im able to get the username and password but unable to access it in the mainpage.jsp which displays the username/password.

```
Servlet

package com.school.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.school.beans.Login;

@Controller
public class Logincontroller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "loginform", new Login());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validatelogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validatelogin(@ModelAttribute("SchoolManagement")Login login, 
               ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("username", login.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("password", login.getPassword());
        System.out.println("useranme = " + login.getUsername());
        System.out.println("password = " + login.getPassword());
        return "mainpage";
    }
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<!-- 
<script src="javascript/login.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css"/>
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/
 -->
 <!--<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>-->
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/login.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/login.js" />"></script>
<script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="middle">
        <form:form method="POST" id="loginform" commandName="loginform" 
        action="/SchoolManagement/validatelogin">
            <form:label path="username"> Username:</form:label>
            <form:input path="username" />  <br>
            <form:label path="password"> Password:</form:label>
            <form:input path="password" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form:form>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

mainpage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>MainPage</title>
</head>


<body>

    <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>${username}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>${password}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cursory glance looks like the @ModelAttribute in your post method has the wrong name

Comment: what should be the @modelattribute name?

Comment: The same as the model passed down to the form, and what is bound to the commandName attribute, so "loginform"

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the gateway?  If i'm not mistaken the action parameter of springs form is already context aware, so /SchoolManagement/validatelogin should just be /validatelogin.  If that's not it, i'm at a loss.

Comment: When I remove /schoolmanagement..it does not work...thanks anyway

Comment: Does it print the username and password when you submit your form?

Comment: Yes, it prints the username and password..The model is not accessible in mainpage.jsp

Comment: What do you mean _not accessible_? Does the rest of the table show? do the username and password get logged with your `System.out.println` commands?

Comment: Did you try returning ModelAndView("viewname", model)?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the values directly out of the request.

```
<%
  String username = (String) request.getAttribute("username");
  String password = (String) request.getAttribute("password");
%>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><%= username %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><%= password %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That should definitely work... if not, something's wrong with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

your command name

```
commandName="loginform"
```

is different than model attribute

```
@ModelAttribute("SchoolManagement")
```

try to use same names